# HTML markup appears before the page loads when using jQuery version 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pageload

I'm using this to import one HTML page into another. When I load or refresh the page the HTML markup appears, then page loads. How can I resolve this error?

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('.header').load("Header.html");
    });
    $(function(){ 
      $('.first').load("leftpanel.html");
    });
    $(function(){
      $('.second').load("banner.html");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
<script>  
 $(function(){
      $('.header').load("Header.html"); 
   });

   $(function(){
       $('.first').load("leftpanel.html"); 
    });
   $(function(){
       $('.second').load("banner.html"); 
    });
      
</script> 
</head>


<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main">
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="first"></div>   

Note: calling commom html page in rest of pages,for that i used js

Comment: You should place your code examples in your question. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sure i'll keep in mind from the next time.

Comment: @JonSaw can you please help me with this? now i have placed code as well

Comment: Can you upgrade your jquery version?

Comment: @exampleone I just tried your code in my server and it's working without any problems. I bet something else is going wrong with one of your pages. Can you show the rest of the code for `Header.html`, `leftpanel.html` and `banner.html`?

Comment: I have created individual page,where i paste the code of common page,so, there will be no common page and no importing issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more specific about what error is happening. Please also note that you don't have to ask for help in the question. That you want help is already assumed so such text is generally considered noise.

Answer (score -1):

Not too sure whether it will work or not but try this-

```
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>


  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $('.header').load("Header.html");
      $('.first').load("leftpanel.html");
      $('.second').load("banner.html");      
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have try this but nothing change.
still facing same problem.I have compressed js file too ,but still it display html first then only page loads